# How to go about making a form in magento which requires image upload

Tags: magento

I am new to magento so basically unable to figure out a solution for a current problem at hand. We have an eCommerce store built on top of magento. Now, we need to have a form in which the user can fill in some details and upload their image. How can this be effectively done in magento.

As of now, I am thinking of having a form page with upload php script and then save the details in CSV text file. Is this the right way to go for it. Also, we might need to add this information as a customer and use it later.

Actually we are starting a monthly item delivery system for which we need to have customers information and photo. Just throw some light on the issue and let me know how to go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below link, it show how to upload and saved a image in Magento.

> http://blog.decryptweb.com/file-upload-magento/